# How to deal with dependable dropdowns in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I am trying to create a dependable dropdown on Django but since my JavaScript/ajax knowledge is not great, I have hit rock bottom. *Note: I have read previous questions on this matter but none of them fully solved my problem.*

**Problem Description:**

Due to my database size, I am retrieving partial data from the server whenever a view is requested. This makes my job of using forms harder since I am using the username of the user to filter my server. Here is a simplified version of my code.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^SpecificVessel', views.SpecificVessel, name="goSpecificVessel"),
]
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def SpecificVessel(request):

  #Get the username to filter the tables from SQL Server:
  username = None
  if request.user.is_authenticated:
      username = request.user.username

  #Get the shipnames. 
  cursor.execute("select distinct SHIPNAME from Table where [GROUP]=" + "'" + username + "'")
  row = cursor.fetchall() 
  df_listofships = pd.DataFrame(data=row, columns=['SHIPNAME'])
  shipnames = list(df_listofships['SHIPNAME'].tolist())  # LIST FOR SHIP SELECTION

  #Get All the data from database.
  cursor.execute("select * from Table2 where [GROUP]=" + "'" + username + "'")
  row = cursor.fetchall()
  df = pd.DataFrame(data=row)
  colnames = list(dftrans.columns.values.tolist()) #LIST FOR YEAR DROPDOWN SELECTION

  #getting the dropdown selections:
  Dropdown_shipname = request.POST.get('Dropdown_shipname')
  Dropdown = request.POST.getlist('Dropdown')
  
  
  return render(request, 'SpecificVessel.html', 
               {'colnames': colnames, 'Dropdown': Dropdown, 'shipnames': shipnames, 'Dropdown_shipname': Dropdown_shipname,})
```

**SpecificVessel.html**

```
<form method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="Dropdown_shipname"><b>Select Vessel</b></label>
               <select name="Dropdown_shipname" id="Dropdown_shipname" data-style="btn-default" class="selectpicker form-control" >
                   {% for i in shipnames %}
                       <option value="{{ i }}" {% if Dropdown_shipname == i %}  selected {% endif %}>{{ i }} </option>
                   {% endfor %}
                </select>
   </div>



   <div class="form-group col-md-4">
       <label for="Dropdown"><b> Select Month </b></label>
             <select name="Dropdown" id="Dropdown" data-style="btn-default" class="selectpicker form-control" multiple>
                  {% for i in colnames %}
                       <option value="{{ i }}" {% if Dropdown == i %}  selected {% endif %} >{{ i }} </option>
                  {% endfor %}
              </select>
   </div>
            

   <div class="form-group col-md-1 margin_top_25">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </div>
            
</form>
```

**What is the problem?**

The solution I have in the code above provides me with independent dropdowns. That is, whenever there is a mismatch, it throws me an error. I have been trying to approach this in different way, however, after long research online, I found out that javascript or ajax may be the way to go about this. My question is this: **Is there any way in which I could get what the user has selected in Dropdown_shipname before he submits the results? If yes, how would you solve this problem?**

I hope I was clear enough. Please let me know if I should explain the problem any better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot I feel I need to address before answering your main question.

1. The `if request.user.is_authenticated` bit is unnecessary; you already decorate the view with `@login_required`, so there's no way the user isn't authenticated.
2. Where does `cursor` come from? It doesn't look like you're using Django's database stuff (the ORM, or even raw cursors), but something else? Why is that?

   - Having a global `cursor` may lead to trouble down the line in production, when it's being shared between requests in a multithreaded situation. (Using Django's database functionality the database connections are correctly reset between requests, and each thread gets its own connection.)
3. Your SQL queries are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, since you're just concatenating strings together. You need to use placeholders (parametrized queries) instead. How that's done depends on the database and database driver you're using.
4. You definitely don't need Pandas and a Pandas dataframe to extract the data from your database result! (My pet peeve: useless use of Pandas.)

   - The first retrieval would be `shipnames = [row[0] for row in cursor]`.
   - The second retrieval would be `colnames = [d[0] for d in cursor.description]` (or similar; depends on your database). (However, you really don't want to fetch a number of rows just to get the column names; one row, e.g. `LIMIT 1` in standard SQL, would do.)
5. You should be using Django forms to manage, well, forms. That way you don't need to manage rendering the `<select>`s and `<option>`s and `selected`s manually.

   - This view would likely become a `FormView` subclass.
   - You say "This makes my job of using forms harder since I am using the username of the user to filter my server.", but that's a non-issue. You can well pass in your Django `request`, or just the `User`, or an `username`, to a custom form class, and have it modify or even add fields dynamically to the form based on it.

That said, the most minimal solution here is a tiny bit of JavaScript, to refresh the page with an added query string argument for the first selection. That is, when the user changes the shipname field, you'd refresh the page with e.g. `?shipname=selection-here`, and deal with figuring out the correct choices for the other field in your view code.

The most minimal way I can think of is

```
<script>
document.getElementById("Dropdown_shipname").addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  location.href = `?shipname=${event.target.value}`;
}, false);
</script>
```

Beyond that, you could use an AJAX request to selectively refresh only part of the page, and beyond that, maybe refactor the form into, say, a React.js or Vue.js component that deals with the form.

But either way, no, you're not going to be able to dynamically change the other field without JavaScript.

Comment: I will answer your bullet points one by one:
1. Thanks for the suggestion. I will improve my code. 
2. I omitted the code because I did not want to over complicate the file.
3. This seems off the topic, but how would you suggest I should go about the SQL server structure?
4. I am using pandas because I am doing some other calculations that I am not showing here.

About the javascript or ajax part, how should I go about it? Is it okay if you show me some code as a guidance?

Comment: Added a minimal example of the JavaScript required.

Comment: One last question. How can I pass the updated selection to my views? Something like: POST.get('Dropdown_shipname') ? Or I need to write something else?

Comment: The query string parameter is available as `request.GET.get('shipname')`.

Comment: Thank you for all the detailed answers. You made my day!